# How to set the background of a layout with a photo from gallery?

Tags: android, background, bitmap

I have been trying to set the background of the main activity with a photo from the gallery. I have added a button and set its listener. In this listener, I defined the intent for result as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
                0);
```

The method I used to receive the result and set the background for the main relative layout is:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 0:
        data.getDataString();
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {

                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                        getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                RelativeLayout bg = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainRL);
                Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),
                        bitmap);
                bg.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Once the button is pressed, the gallery opens and I can choose photos but after that it crashes. The logCat when the the crash happened is:

```
11-20 21:32:53.381: D/dalvikvm(16734): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 77K, 8% free 9300K/10051K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
11-20 21:32:53.391: I/dalvikvm-heap(16734): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.075MB for 1521016-byte allocation
11-20 21:32:53.431: D/dalvikvm(16734): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 7% free 10785K/11591K, paused 14ms+2ms, total 37ms
11-20 21:32:53.721: I/webclipboard(16734): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@427823b0
11-20 21:32:53.791: I/webclipboard(16734): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@427823b0
11-20 21:32:53.891: D/dalvikvm(16734): GC_CONCURRENT freed 270K, 8% free 10993K/11847K, paused 13ms+12ms, total 40ms
11-20 21:32:54.012: I/webclipboard(16734): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@427823b0
11-20 21:32:54.282: D/dalvikvm(16734): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads550927314.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
11-20 21:32:54.412: D/dalvikvm(16734): GC_CONCURRENT freed 207K, 7% free 11673K/12487K, paused 16ms+16ms, total 87ms
11-20 21:32:54.422: V/webkit(16734): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {4277cc40}
11-20 21:32:54.452: D/ProgressBar(16734): setProgressDrawable mProgressDrawable = null, d = android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable@427997a8needUpdate = false
11-20 21:32:54.462: D/ProgressBar(16734): setProgress = 0
11-20 21:32:54.462: D/ProgressBar(16734): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
11-20 21:32:54.462: D/ProgressBar(16734): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 17
11-20 21:32:54.472: W/ResourceType(16734): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c9 (t=7 e=713) in package 0 (error -75)
11-20 21:33:14.943: W/dalvikvm(16967): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c612a0)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.robotaaly.unitbulletconverter/com.robotaaly.unitbulletconverter.CalculationActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at com.robotaaly.unitbulletconverter.CalculationActivity.calculateFnc(CalculationActivity.java:827)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at com.robotaaly.unitbulletconverter.CalculationActivity.access$0(CalculationActivity.java:825)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at com.robotaaly.unitbulletconverter.CalculationActivity$2.onTextChanged(CalculationActivity.java:404)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7398)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3730)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3585)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:95)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3560)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.widget.TextView.onRestoreInstanceState(TextView.java:3460)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:12012)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2651)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2651)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2651)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2651)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:11990)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1826)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:949)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:921)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1145)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2070)
11-20 21:33:14.993: E/AndroidRuntime(16967):    ... 11 more
11-20 21:33:15.013: I/Ads(16967): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_getSdkConstants();AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":0,"session_id":"14165905526806045037","seq_num":"1","slotname":"a1524d822019181","u_w":320,"msid":"com.robotaaly.unitbulletconverter","adtest":"on","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.4.1","bas_off":0,"net":"null","app_name":"4.android.com.robotaaly.unitbulletconverter","hl":"en","gnt":8,"carrier":"50212","u_audio":1,"kw":[],"u_sd":1.5,"ms":"-JTEbDWqE5u7nUwF2aVwW9cvXVI5UmAeTnAwp_7nyxZY6Az-TVS6TEfG4RGORwQh4OqQNvA4oR5N_L9JJwubWzQazduuBeiGe7bnMOCDQDehxNgy8uuKeiZUmzaKyoyHopVay-XniTmGhjXJ0QQtpQb1Yc4y0rN87j8xGADQKXxX2aFnGkVp-iwhbRBPetLExiQ_U6m-eVeeogJ7Num_zQksZE7XdOds9ChR0idznXGE0sTZqaGy0O1L8oTsjrs7X4tczIDwM_s-nHjzXEQyUQzunKyzxBLsNNXfiPA_3_t-CoV1YDVB9kNltYsag0QpOFfIRhC0i8LfdcV-02mBTw","mv":"16.android","isu":"27B6214A0270F283668371709772C538","format":"320x50_mb","oar":0,"ad_pos":{"height":0,"visible":0,"y":0,"x":0,"width":0},"u_h":533,"pt":1,"bas_on":0,"ptime":0});</script></head><body></body></html>
```

What wrong thing is with this code?
Thank you

Comment: Show us the log trace of the crash.

Comment: what is there at `CalculationActivity.java:827` ?

Comment: @AnkitPopli This is the code at line 827:`if (fromUnits.length > from && fromUnits.length > to) {
   fromUnitText = fromUnits[from];
   toUnitText = fromUnits[to];
  }`

Comment: @DamienR. I have edited the question with the logCat included.

Comment: Try to test and log if your values fromUnits/from/fromUnits[from]/fromUnits[to] are equal to null. There is probably one of them that == null.

Comment: @DamienR. , Well, I added this code to detect the null condition: `if(fromUnits==null || (Integer) from == null || (Integer)to == null)
  {
   
  }`. If this condition is faced, everything next is skipped because I put all of the code after this in the else statement. It seems that it fixed some problems; the selected photo is now set as background to the layout but the popup window to choose the image source appears again even without clicking the button. If I touch the back button to skip this photo source popup, it crashes again.

Comment: @DamienR. How may I post the logCat? It's too long to fit in a comment.

Comment: @RobotAaly:  remove `data.getDataString()` and try again..

Comment: @DamienR. You are awesome! Thank you so much. Everything works great :).
I'm greedy a bit to ask another question if you know. Since the image is now imported from gallery, how may I save it in the drawable resource folder to load it as background each time the app is started?

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped.
For your question, sorry but it's not possible.
What you can do is save the path of your image in Preference or in a Database, and load it when you need to.

Comment: All right! I checked this question too. I'll check the way how to get the image path and load it. I appreciate your help. Happy day to you.@DamienR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem was because of the `null` values returned by fromUnits. The second time your app is crashing when you press back is because you are trying to get Data string even when the result is not OK. i.e outside `if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)`. Either remove that statement completely since you are not using it or move that inside the `if` condition if need that.

Answer (score 0):

Start the intent for picking the image:

```
Intent galleryIntent = new  Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 002);
```

Receive your image here:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (requestCode == 002 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        //Get the picked image uri
        String picturePath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImage);
        Bitmap bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, null);
        bg.setBackgroundDrawable(bmp);
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```